# Cracking ZIP password from spanned volume

Tags: passwords, zip, archiving, floppy

On October 10, 1997, I tried to free up some space on my hard-drive by off-loading them to floppy disks. I tried to reduce the number of disks required by using PKZIP to compress them. For some reason, I encrypted the archive with a password (hey, I had just started university and was experimenting ).

Recently, I began the arduous process of imaging every single floppy disk I have, during which, I found a batch of 37 disks containing the aforementioned archive. Needless to say, I cannot for the life of me remember what the password was. I tried everything I might have used and even tried to put myself in my young self’s mindset. No luck.

Looking around for a ZIP-password-cracker, I found that *John the Ripper* seems to get the most love. I let it run for a couple of days on the data set, but then it occurred to me that maybe it does not even understand spanned volumes. The manual doesn't seem to mention anything about spanned archives, nor can I find anything on the Internet.

Can anyone confirm that John the Ripper can indeed crack passwords of ZIP archives spanned on multiple disks? Alternately, does anybody know of another way to crack it?

(Each of the 37 disks contains a file with its position in the archive from `PKBACK#.001` to `PKBACK#.037`. Also, disk 34 has a few bad sectors towards the end. ☹)

Comment: You do realize that those few bad sectors (which I assume means that particular part of the archive is corrupt) will likely make it impossible to extract the archive, right?

Comment: This particular archive contains lots of little files, so the bad sectors will make the files stored in that part (and maybe one or two files before and after) impossible to extract, but the rest of the files in the archive will extract just fine. I know. I've been there, done that. Multiple times. There's over 1,400 floppies I'm currently in the process of imaging.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: Not yet.  *<filler text because SO won't allow comments that are "too short", whatever that means >*